# How do I represent polymorphic objects in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a schema for a JSON object that varies its schema depending on the value of one of its properties: `type`.

Like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["INT", "PERCENT"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["type"],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {"type": {"const": "INT"}}
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "value": {"type": "number", "multipleOf": 1}
        },
        "required": ["value"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {"type": {"const": "PERCENT"}}
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "value": {"type": "number"},
          "min": {"type": "number"},
          "max": {"type": "number"}
        },
        "required": ["value", "min", "max"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm getting all sorts of misbehaviour from the various validators I'm trying.

Some examples with problems noted after the `//`:

```
{
    "type": "PERCENT", // property type has not been defined(?!)
    "value": 0.0,
    "min": 10,
    "max": 25
}

{
    "type": "INT", // no errors allowed, and value 
    "value": 0.1,  // should've been flagged as not multiple of 1
    "min": 10,  // should've been flagged as disallowed additional property
    "max": 25 // same as above
}
```

[Here's the validator I'm trying](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've figured out that the problem is that `addtionalProperties` only considers the properties defined in the sub-schema it's defined in. That's why you have to include the "type" property in your `then`. You have a few options that are an improvement over the solution you posted that you weren't happy with.

#### Option 1: `unevaluatedProperties`

Draft 2019-09 introduced the `unevaluatedProperties` keyword. If you use this at the top level of your schema and don't use `addtionalProperties` anywhere, you will get the behavior you expected from `additionalProperties`. I see you are using draft-07, so you have to upgrade in order to use this solution.

#### Option 2: Boolean schemas

The solution you came up with is to re-define the "type" property in the `then` schemas. `additionalProperties` just needs "type" to be declared, you don't need to include the schema for it again. You can use `true` or the empty schema `{}` instead.

#### Option 3: `propertyNames`

Instead of `additionalProperties` you can use `propertyNames`. This allows you to declare a list of which property names are allowed in the object rather than hacking `additionalProperties` with `true` or `{}` to figure out the allowed property names the way you want it to.

Comment: thanks! - I'm actually trying to use the 2020 schema and the cli validator I'm using `jsonschema 3.2.0` works well with the propertyNames/unevaluatedProperties combo.

Answer (score 0):

well I found a way to get what I wanted, but it doesn't mean I like it. Having to redefine "type" doesn't seem right to me.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["INT", "PERCENT"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["type"],
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {"type": {"const": "INT"}}
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "value": {"type": "number", "multipleOf": 1},
          "type": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["value", "type"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {"type": {"const": "PERCENT"}}
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "value": {"type": "number"},
          "min": {"type": "number"},
          "max": {"type": "number"},
          "type": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["value", "min", "max", "type"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

tests...

This validates:

```
{
    "type": "PERCENT", 
    "value": 0,
    "min": 10,
    "max": 20
}
```

so does this:

```
{
    "type": "INT", 
    "value": 0
}
```

this errors in the way I want:

```
{
    "type": "INT", 
    "value": 0.1,  // not a multiple of 1
    "min": 4, //  not expected
    "max": 5 // not expected
}
```

and so does this:

```
{
    "type": "PERCENT", 
    "value": 0.1,
    "max": 5   // min is a required property
}
```